# checking if the success data is empty in ajax method of jquery

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I have two select boxes in my form.when a user select an option of first select box the options of second select box will be shown by jquery ajax.My problem is that some options of first select box has no record in database and when they selected the second select box should not be shown.I need to check if the data is empty .I treid this code but nothing happens
view:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#subsec').hide();
        $('section').change(){
            var sec_id=$(this).val();
            var url='article_controler/get_options/'+sec_id;

            $.ajax({
                url:url,
                type:'post',
                success:function(resp){
                    if(!resp)
                        $('#subsec').hide();
                    else 
                        $('#subsec').show();
                        $('$subsec').html(resp)

                })
            }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Could you also show use your `get_options` function in your controller?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
 $.ajax({
                url:url,
                type:'post',
                success:function(resp){
                    if(resp == "" || resp == null){
                        $('#subsec').hide();
                    }
                    else {
                            $('#subsec').show();
                            $('#subsec').html(resp);
                        }

                })
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi pls try this,

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#subsec').hide();
    $('#firstSelectBoxId').change("selectboxMethod");

    });

   function selectboxMethod(){
   var sec_id=$("#firstSelectBoxId").val();
   alert("Selected from first select"+sec_id);
   if(sec_id != null){
    var url='article_controler/get_options/'+sec_id;
     $.ajax({
         url:url,
         type:'post',
        success:function(resp){

            $('#subsec').show();
            $('#subsec').html(resp);
        }

      });
   }else{
      $("#subsec").hide();
    }

  }

  </script>
```

Comment: if first select box having empty value from database u wnt to hide the second select box. am i correct. If not pls explain

Comment: Hi, I have edited the code now pls use this. Give correct id. And Let me know if select null value from first select.what it display in alert..pls try this

Answer (score 0):

I have added inline comments to help you out

```
class Article_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function get_options()
    {
        $option = $this->input->post('option'); // validate this

        //Get a list of Sub options from your model
        $model = ''; //your own implementation here

        //If no model data returned, send a 404 status header
        //and bail
        if(!$model){
            return $this->output->set_status_header(404);
        }

        $responce = array(
            'suboptions'  =>  $model // array of suboptions the model returned
        );

        // Ideally Abstract all the Ajax stuff to 
        // its own controller to keep things Dry
        return $this->output
            ->set_status_header(200)
            ->set_content_type('application/json')
            ->set_output(json_encode($responce));
    }
}
```

-

```
 //Global URL variable or put it in <base href>
    var URL = "<?php echo site_url();?>";

    (function($){
        var myForm = {
            init : function(){
                //initialize myForm object properties here
                this.Form = $("form#myFormID");
                this.selectChange = this.Form.find("select#mySelectBoxI");
                this.newSelect = this.Form.find("select#secondaryselectboxId");

                //hide second select with CSS by default

                //Bind the Change event to our object(myForm) method
                this.selectChange.on('change', $.proxy(this.ChangedEvent, this)); 
            },

            ChangedEvent : function(event){ // gets the change event

            //Grab the currentTarget(option[i]) value from the event received
            //You may also need to pass the CSRF Token
                this.buildAjaxRequest({'option' : event.currentTarget.value});
            },

            buildAjaxRequest : function( data ){
                var config = {
                    cache : false,
                    url : URL + 'article_controller/get_options',
                    method : 'POST',
                    data : data, //'option' : event.currentTarget.value
                    dataType : 'json'
                };

                this.makeAjaxRequest(config).then(
                    $.proxy(this.ResponceHandler, this),
                    $.proxy(this.ErrorHandler, this)
                );
            },

            makeAjaxRequest : function( config ){
                return $.ajax( config ).promise();
            },

            ResponceHandler : function( data ){
                $.each(data.suboptions, function(i, v){
                    this.newSelect.append('<option value="'.data[i].'">'.data[v].'</option>');');
                });
                this.newSelect.show();
            },

            ErrorHandler : function(xhr, statusText, exception){
                switch(xhr.status)
                {
                    case 404: //remember the 404 from the controller
                        alert(xhr.statusText); //handle your own way here
                    break;
                }
            },

        }

        myForm.init();
    }(jQuery));
```